# .htaccess Редирект на страницу, если нет QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess, запрос, redirect, apache2, http-status-code-301

Собственно, подскажите, как сделать редирект на /page.php, если URL не содержит *QUERY_STRING*. Исключение составляет сама /page.php

Примеры:

c http://site.com на http://site.com/page.php

c http://site.com/page2/ на http://site.com/page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page.php
RewriteRule .* /page.php [L]
```